# Understanding scala binary compatibility on my example

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependencies

I have some scala program which uses `spark-2.4.6` framework.
My code is compiled with `scala-2.12.12`.

1. How can I check if my code (compiled to class files) is compatible with `spark-2.4.6`?
2. How can I check what version of scala compiler is used to build class of spark?
3. What does it mean binary compatibility here? Is there exists list of compatible scala compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/  Look at the docs per version. It states the scala versions needed.

Comment: > Spark runs on Java 8, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.5+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.7 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x).         on https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/   Does it mean that my code can be compiled with scala-2.12.x as long as I use `spark-2.4.7`?

Comment: yes, for this version. for another version look at the corresponding version doc.